# Efficient way to find indices of topmost True values in 2d boolean array (Python)

Tags: python, boolean

Suppose I have a 2d boolean array with shape (nrows,ncols). I'm trying to efficiently extract the indices of the topmost True value for each column in the array. If the column has all False values, then no indices are returned for that column. Below is an example of a boolean array with shape (4,6) where the indices of the bold **Trues** would be the desired output.

False False False False False False

**True**  False False **True**  False False

True   False **True**  False False **True**

True   False True   True   False False

Desired output of indices (row,col): [(1,0),(2,2),(1,3),(2,5)]

I tried using numpy.where and also an implementation of the skyline algorithm but both options are slow. Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: don't think there's a better way here than walking each column from top to bottom until first True

Comment: Define "efficient". You have to walk the whole array, so you can't do better than `O(n^2)`. You can only try to avoid a large constant overhead.

Comment: @Thomas I think you mean O(N) on the size of the array.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillage Sure. I was thinking of the problem size `n` as the number of rows + columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to detect the first `True` values.

Prepare the example array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
[[0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,0,0,1,0,0],
 [1,0,1,0,0,1],
 [1,0,1,1,0,0]]).astype('bool')
a
```

Output

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False, False]])
```

Stack one row of `False` to deal with columns without a `True`. Find first `True` in every column with `np.argmax` and append an arange for the row indices. You have to adjust the column indices by `-1` because we added one row to the array. Then select the columns where the `True`'s index was greater than `0`

```
b = np.vstack([np.zeros_like(a[0]),a])
t = b.argmax(axis=0)
np.vstack([t - 1, np.arange(len(a[0]))]).T[t > 0]
```

Output

```
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 5]])
```

---

Translating [@HenryYik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049422/14277722) answer to numpy gives a one line solution

```
np.vstack([a.argmax(axis=0), np.arange(len(a[0]))]).T[a.sum(0) > 0]
```

Output

```
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using `pandas`, you can construct a df, drop columns with False only and then `idxmax`:

```
arr = [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [True, False, False, True, False, False],
       [True, False, True, False, False, True],
       [True, False, True, True, False, False]]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=range(len(arr[0])))

s = df.loc[:, df.sum()>0].idxmax()
print (s)
```

Result:

```
0    1
2    2
3    1
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Which is col value vs row value. You can convert it back to your desired form:

```
print (list(zip(s, s.index)))

[(1, 0), (2, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: Can I copy your `sum` idea to my solution to show how this would work in `numpy`?

Comment: Sure go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
def get_topmost(ar: np.ndarray):
    return [(row.index(True), i) for i, row in enumerate(ar.T.tolist()) if True in row]
```

Example: (should works as is)

```
>>> test = np.array([
    [False, False, False, False, False, False],
    [True,  False, False, True,  False, False],
    [True,  False, True,  False, False, True],
    [True,  False, True,  True,  False, False],
])

>>> print(get_topmost(test))
[(1, 0), (2, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5)]
```